# How to check if "100" matches anything in the database that starts wtih "100"?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular project, and I can't figure out how to check input value to database value.
Like, I want to retrieve data from a table that matches my input, but it should not EQUAL the value.
Like, I have an table of 1001, 1002, 1003, 1201, 1202, 1203 and I want my input of 100 to show me all results that start with 100...

```
  onKey(value: string) {
this.values = value;
return this.values;
```

}

this is my code for the HTML input.

```
      <input matInput type="text"
  placeholder=""
  #box (keyup)="onKey(box.value)"
  >
```

this is my html.

and the actually place where I do the matching

```
 this.service.getOverview().then(each => {
  each.filter(data => {
    if (data.keyNr === this.onKey(this.values)) {
      return true;
    }
  }).forEach(data => {...............................
```

I am using === right now, because I don't know how to do anything else..

edit: I think I made a mistake with my question.
I have a table with data, I want to filter things out.
I mean, I still need the filter, but instead of using value === entered value, I want to match that string instead.

Comment: I think you are after a filter function: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51416513/filter-array-that-contains-specific-symbol-or-words-in-javascript

Comment: use string.startsWith function

Comment: string.startsWith? Will that work inside the if ()?
Going to try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @esnezz,

I used your answer and it seems like it works perfectly.
I am not sure how reliable it is but it is working fine now.

```
this.service.getOverview().then(each => {
  each.filter(data => {
    // if (data.keyNr === this.onKey(this.values)) {
    if (data.keyNr.toString().startsWith(this.onKey(this.values)) 
      return true;
    }
```

I changed my code to that.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite brute force but you can try casting the key to string and checking the first three characters, like this:

```
this.service.getOverview().then(each => {
each.filter(data => {
if (data.keyNr.toString().substr(0,3) == value.toString().substr(0,3) {
  return true;
}
//eccetera...
```

You can also cast a numver into a string with `Number.toString(variable)`

Comment: Oh wow, this looks like this is going to the right direction, 
but, how do I ...
I mean, if I search for 100.. then he gives me everything that starts with 100..
But if I want to specify and search for 1001... he still gives me everything that starts with 100... instead of 1001..

Comment: this.service.getOverview().then(each => {
each.filter(data => {
if (data.keyNr.toString().substr(0, value.toString().length)== value.toString(){
  return true;
}

Comment: Right answer from Ravi!